# What is the size of the minimum image that ArUco can detect?

Tags: opencv, aruco

I already tried two different size of markers one is 100 pixel equal 3.2cm*3.2cm, and the other is more bigger than that.

I mean I can't print much more size of marker to detect.

So , I'm wondering what is the size of the minimum image that **ArUco** can detect?

Comment: The 100 pixels marker can not detected by my camera.

Comment: The image size that can be detect is determined by your camera sensor resolution... the minimum or contour length of your rectangle is about 0.04 of max(image_row,image_col)

Comment: @user1538798 where did you take this information from?

Comment: @Simon  https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html